# How to disable pagination if data less than 6 or etc ?? (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I Want to disable pagination if data less than 6,
It's my script on controller :

```
 function index(){

    $per_page= $this->input->get('per_page');
    $data['brand'] = $this->brand_model->brand();
    $data['type'] = $this->type_model->type();
    $data['city'] = $this->city_model->city();
    $data['location'] = $this->location_model->location();
    $data['history']= $this->history_transaksi_model->history($to,$per_page);

    $pagination['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $pagination['base_url'] = site_url().'history/?';
    $pagination['total_rows'] = 10;
    $pagination['per_page'] = 5;
    $pagination['uri_segment'] = 6;
    $pagination['num_links'] = 3;


    $pagination['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $pagination['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $pagination['first_link'] = '<<';
    $pagination['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $pagination['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['last_link'] = '>>';
    $pagination['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $pagination['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['next_link'] = '>';
    $pagination['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $pagination['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['prev_link'] = '<';
    $pagination['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $pagination['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $pagination['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $pagination['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $pagination['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $this->pagination->initialize($pagination);
    $this->load->view('history.php',$data);
}
```

On my view i'm use If statement ,but when the data is more than 5, the pagination doesn't showed,and the sixth data or more doesn't appears too.

```
<?php 

if(count($history->result())==0 || count($history->result()) <=5  ){

}else{
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for & what you are doing is wrong

You are doing

```
$data['history']= $this->history_transaksi_model->history($to,$per_page);//Here actually you are getting data for the page e.g page 3 data
```

> Here you should be counting total rows e.g you have 100 rows of data for this pagination

```
$pagination['total_rows'] = 10;
```

> This should be a method call to your table from your model or to a
>   direct db call to table for getting total number of records for this
>   pagination

```
$pagination['total_rows'] = $this->history_transaksi_model->get_total_rows();//if you have any search params pass it to the method
```

Also my suggestion is although you have less then 6 records you are creating pagination.

```
$data['pagination']= '';//init pagination value

if (($pagination['total_rows'] = $this->history_transaksi_model->get_total_rows()) > 5) {
    $pagination['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $pagination['base_url'] = site_url().'history/?';
    $pagination['total_rows'] = 10;
    $pagination['per_page'] = 5;
    $pagination['uri_segment'] = 6;
    $pagination['num_links'] = 3;


    $pagination['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $pagination['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $pagination['first_link'] = '<<';
    $pagination['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $pagination['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['last_link'] = '>>';
    $pagination['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $pagination['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['next_link'] = '>';
    $pagination['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $pagination['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['prev_link'] = '<';
    $pagination['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $pagination['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $pagination['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $pagination['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $pagination['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $pagination['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $this->pagination->initialize($pagination);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

}
```

if you have custom **`HTML`** wrapped with pagination

```
if ( ! empty($pagination) ) {
    echo '<div class="pagination">' . $pagination . '</div>';
}
```

else just **`echo`** it

```
echo $pagination;
```